# how can i make 1 1/2 cup of all purpose flour to 1 1/2 cup of self'rising flour?

Tags: baking

I am making a coffee cake it requires *self-rising flou*r but I only have all purpose flour. I do know how to make ap flour to self-rising yet i dnt the measurments for 1/2 a cup ?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://addapinch.com/cooking/2012/04/27/how-to-make-self-rising-flour/) has a pretty typical ratio:

1 c. flour : 1 1/2 tsp baking powder : 1/4 tsp salt

so for 1 1/2 cup, you would want:

1.2 c. flour, 2 1/4 tsp baking powder : 3/8 tsp salt

Alternatively, you could make a fairly large batch, whisk it together well, then measure normally.